# How to merge a column in a dataframe with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

df1:

```
| Ref        | Call        |
|:-----------|------------:|
| E/123      | Research    |   
| E/164      | Research    |   
| E/256      | Research    |    
| E/543      | Fellow      |    
| E/213      | Fellow      |   
| E/457      | Fellow      |
```

df2:

```
| Ref        | Grade       | Person       |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| E/123      |        6    |   A.Smith    | 
| E/164      |        4    |   P.Davies   | 
| E/256      |        4    |   E.Carter   |  
| E/543      |        8    |   D.White    |  
| E/213      |        9    |   R.Daniels  |  
| E/457      |        2    |   S.Conner   |
```

I want to add a new column to `df2`, which takes the `'Call'` column from `df1`, and then matches the `call` to the `ref` number i.e.:

```
| Ref        | Grade       | Person       | Call     |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:---------|
| E/123      |        6    |   A.Smith    | Research |
| E/164      |        4    |   P.Davies   | Research |
| E/256      |        4    |   E.Carter   | Research | 
| E/543      |        8    |   D.White    | Fellow   |
| E/213      |        9    |   R.Daniels  | Fellow   | 
| E/457      |        2    |   S.Conner   | Fellow   |
```

Obviously my script is not as simple as the above example (i.e. it isnt in a nice order, it has to be matched `ref` to `ref`), so `df1` is a list of ALL the grants we have and their respective `call`, `df2` is a 'random' sample which can be big or small.

Comment: Did you just do `pd.concat([df1, df2], 1)`?

Comment: Ill try now. I didnt realise it was that simple.

Comment: If it works, this is a dupe. Otherwise, edit your data to account for the failing case. ;-)

Comment: Just tried it, it doesnt seem to be doing anything?

Comment: Okay. Then, try: `df1.merge(df2, on='Ref')`. Seriously!

Comment: Ill try now. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, the concat is working, but it is bringing through the ref number (i.e. I now have two reference numbers instead of bringing the call through)?

Comment: You can just call `df.drop('Ref', 1)` on one of the data frames. Alternatively, merge will drop that duplicate column automatically.

Comment: The merge is not working unfortunately i.e. nothing happens (no errors, but doesnt add the call column), and the concat is not bringing the call column over

Comment: This Will Work. `pd.concat([df1.drop('Ref', 1), df2], axis=1)`

Comment: There must be something wrong with my dataset. It still isnt copying the call into the new dataframe. I checked the headers of the df1 and it says 'Call', 'Ref', yet the 'Call' never gets added. Oh well, I will mess around and try and find a fix. Thank you ColdSpeed

Comment: Found my problem. I was printing it to excel which was using column values I had set up before (which did not have 'Call' in)... I am an idiot, and now I wont make this mistake again. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding.

Comment: Sorry, this question needs to be opened up again. I forgot what I was trying to do... I am not trying to merge two datasets together, I am trying to match calls against ref numbers i.e. df1 could be 10 lines long and df2 could be 20,000. If I concat or merge, it just adds 10 lines to df2 which could be 20,000 lines long.

Comment: Better still, delete this and repost, and make sure you edit your question to reflect this!

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will do that now